# Is it possible to tilt pdf in Preview?

Tags: macos, pdf, preview

as you know we mostly forgot pdf applications other than Preview, yet it may not came handy for every task.
I have scanned some documents recently and need to tilt them only a few degrees right or left.

Is it possible to do that using Preview?

P.S. I am also open to other software or web app suggestions.

Answer (score 3):

Try using the `Terminal`!

Type:

```
sips -r 5 --padColor FFFFFF test.pdf
```

Where 5 is the degrees, FFFFFF is for white (the background) and test.pdf is your pdf. To more easily use this, try only typing `sips -r 5 --padColor FFFFFF` and then drag a file on the terminal.

**Edit:** as user3439894 correctly points out this only works for single page pdf's and overwrites the original. You can append `--out newname.pdf` to the orginal command to create a new file instead. With a multipage document you could also export single pages, run the command on individual pages and then combine them again, though that will take some effort.

Comment: What if it's a multi-page pdf document?  The command as written it will wipe out all pages other then the first page, thus destroying the document.

Comment: @user3439894 what about if you export that page - rotate and import ?

Comment: @Buscar웃, yes of course that is doable however the point I was trying to make is Tumtum's answer as written is destructive to a multi-page pdf document and therefore as written is not a totally acceptable answer as it assumes a single page document.

Comment: @user3439894 it would help if you specify that in your Question, as it is right now it does not say it is multi-page.

Comment: @Buscar웃, I'm not the one who posted the question, only commented on Tumtum's answer and IMO my comment is quite appropriate since the answer will destroy a multi-page pdf document without warning!  Multi-page image pdf documents are not uncommon.

Comment: @user3439894 very true, I added it to my answer